# Filter dynamic ip addresses in Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, php, cookies, dynamic, google-analytics

I am new here and really really stuck and can't figure out another method to filter out dynamic ip address in our google analytics.

What I need to do is filter out our internal users but after checking 6 of our internal user's ip address, Almost all of us have dynamic ip addresses

I have tried:

**Local storage:**

I added the both this code in a private page in our site 
references: https://www.daniscross.co.uk/2016/10/exclude-all-internal-site-visits-from-google-analytics-dynamic-ip/

I visited that private page and checked my content settings for cookies and can confirm that there is the local storage cookie but checked and I still show up in real time reports

**Using cookies, GTM manager and custom variables:**
references: https://www.ohow.co/exclude-dynamic-ip-google-analytics/

so far, I tested with this though I can see the cookie I created using bookmarklet I was not able to filter out my even my own ip after visiting the tag "/?internal" and onto the next pages.

**Browser Extension:**
I have researched about this and I think I found this too time consuming and not that ideal but i haven't tried this method.

Any suggestion is very appreciated.

PS. also checked references to this [How to exclude traffic in Google Analytics from Dynamic IP addresses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22295538/how-to-exclude-traffic-in-google-analytics-from-dynamic-ip-addresses)

[How to filter myself out of Google Analytics with a dynamic IP address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/621200/how-to-filter-myself-out-of-google-analytics-with-a-dynamic-ip-address)

Currently: Nothing seems to work so far yet.

Thank you!

**Update 1:** I have tested the bad hostname method in this site:
https://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2017/08/10/a-better-alternative-to-exclude-filters-in-google-analytics/

I think I still show up in he real time reports

Answer (score 0):

You should go for the browser extension router (which is not particularly time consuming at least for all the desktop browsers I have tried).

For the benefit of others who read this, first make sure that your outward pointing IP is indeed dynamic, and that your are not accidentely looking at internal IPs within a company network.

The obvious problem with filtering dynamic IP addresses is that you don't know them in advance, so you have either to throw out the whole block owned by you DynDNS provider or update your filter every time your address changes (in theory this could be scripted, but that's not really feasible).

The browser extensions chooses another approach by not looking at IP addresses, but instead dismissing calls to the Google Analytics endpoint. The added advantage is that you can still look at a debugger to check your GA implementation. You can have the same effect via a local proxy server - as I am prone to say, "[Don't exclude, rewrite](http://www.flesheatingarthropods.org/with-your-own-ga-requests-dont-exclude-rewrite/)" - which could apply the setting to all programs on your computer at once, as long as you have the proxy running.

If all your internal users sit behind a single router you could probably also set up the router to filter out calls to Google Analytics.

Comment: I think using a browser extension would cut off stats on all sites I visit? Correct me If I am wrong.

Comment: also, I have tested the bad hostname method located in the lunametrics link in your site but I think I still show up at real time reports? How do I know whether i fully filtered out our internal users?